# Add translation to a script option line inside JS as a variable

Tags: javascript, html, prestashop, smarty

I am working with Prestashop and I need to add a translatable text inside the JS file. In the TPL file, I added the below:

```
{strip}
{addJsDefL name=showmore}{l s='Show all' d='Shop.Theme.Actions' js=1}{/addJsDefL}
{addJsDefL name=showless}{l s='Show less' d='Shop.Theme.Actions' js=1}{/addJsDefL}
{/strip}
```

According to Prestashop, I believe the codes above generate this:
var showmore= 'Show all';
var showless= 'Show less';

Then in the JS file, I did this to include the translatable text inside the "text" option below:

```
$('.demo').curtail({
  limit: 140,
  toggle: true,
  text: ['" + showless + "', '" + showmore + "']
});
```

I suspect I made a mistake with the way I added var inside the square bracket as `text: ['" + showless + "', '" + showmore + "']` it did not work.
Any idea on what to do?

Comment: Try '"'+showless+'"',' " ' + showmore + ' " '

Answer (score 0):

If you need an array for your text parameter just use this `text: [showless, showmore]`. You do not need to use any quotes because you already get strings.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding below in the TPL file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    // Translations
    var showmore = '{l s='Show all' d='Shop.Theme.Actions' js=1}';
    var showless = '{l s='Show less' d='Shop.Theme.Actions' js=1}';
//]]>
</script>
```

I then add this to the option of the JS file

```
text: [(showless), (showmore)]
```